# Caption in dmath* equation

Tags: equations, breqn

I have the following equation which I need to reference elsewhere in the paper. It is for a paper in IEEE double-column format which dmath* seems to make the equation fit very well. I do however need to add a label and caption to this for reference in other parts of the paper.

```
%% The equation in question...
\begin{dmath*}
        \left({1 \over ({x^2 \over 9} +  4y^2 + 4z^2)^4 } + 
        {1 \over ({y^2 \over 9} +  4x^2 + 4z^2)^4} +
        {1 \over (({4x \over 3} - 4)^2 + {16y^2 \over 9} +
        {16z^2 \over 9})^4} + {1 \over (({4x \over 3} + 4)^2 + {16y^2 \over 9} +
        {16z^2 \over 9})^4} + {1 \over (({4y \over 3} - 4)^2 + {16x^2 \over 9} +
        {16z^2 \over 9})^4} + {1 \over (({4y \over 3} + 4)^2 + {16x^2 \over 9} +
        {16z^2 \over 9})^4}\right)^ {- {1\over 4}} - 1
\end{dmath*}
```

I've tried simply adding a label and caption

```
%% The equation in question...
\begin{dmath*}
        \left({1 \over ({x^2 \over 9} +  4y^2 + 4z^2)^4 } + 
        {1 \over ({y^2 \over 9} +  4x^2 + 4z^2)^4} +
        {1 \over (({4x \over 3} - 4)^2 + {16y^2 \over 9} +
        {16z^2 \over 9})^4} + {1 \over (({4x \over 3} + 4)^2 + {16y^2 \over 9} +
        {16z^2 \over 9})^4} + {1 \over (({4y \over 3} - 4)^2 + {16x^2 \over 9} +
        {16z^2 \over 9})^4} + {1 \over (({4y \over 3} + 4)^2 + {16x^2 \over 9} +
        {16z^2 \over 9})^4}\right)^ {- {1\over 4}} - 1
\caption{Bloomenthal Algebraic Jack}
\label{eq:BloomenthalJack}
\end{dmath*}
```

but that does not work as dmath* is not a float.

I've also tried putting it between `\begin{equation}` and `\end{equation}`, which puts everything one one line and is also not a float. `\begin{figure}` and `\end{figure}` make it a float, but call it a figure and puts the entire equation on one line.

Does anyone have a way to add a caption and get proper formatting of an equation?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It has never been possible to caption a math display.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to create a reference and label pair though?

Comment: Just use `\label` and `\ref`

Comment: I put the `\label` and `\ref`, but no label shows up next to the equation, and clicking the reference takes me to some section header that isn't on the same page.

Comment: I suppose you have to use `dmath` and not `dmath*`, but I'm no expert with `breqn`.

Comment: @Evan you can try writing label like option for `dmath` environment; i.e., `\begin{dmath}[label={eq:BloomenthalJack}]`

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you'd be OK with making your equation into a float, as long as it's not labeled "Figure" or "Table" or such. So let's [use the `float` package to define a new float](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Custom_floats) called `eqn`. By calling `\floatname{eqn}{Equation}`, we ensure that if you add a caption to the `eqn` environment, that caption will look like "Equation 1: ..."

```
\usepackage{float}
\newfloat{eqn}{htbp}{loe}
\floatname{eqn}{Equation}
```

Additionally, you can do what you want inside the float: `breqn` still breaks your equation, and you can use `\label` and `\ref` as with any other float.

[image]

Here's the code I used to get that image.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{float}
\newfloat{eqn}{htbp}{loe}
\floatname{eqn}{Equation}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[6]
\begin{eqn}
\begin{dmath*}
\left({1 \over ({x^2 \over 9} +  4y^2 + 4z^2)^4 } + 
        {1 \over ({y^2 \over 9} +  4x^2 + 4z^2)^4} +
        {1 \over (({4x \over 3} - 4)^2 + {16y^2 \over 9} +
        {16z^2 \over 9})^4} + {1 \over (({4x \over 3} + 4)^2 + {16y^2 \over 9} +
        {16z^2 \over 9})^4} + {1 \over (({4y \over 3} - 4)^2 + {16x^2 \over 9} +
        {16z^2 \over 9})^4} + {1 \over (({4y \over 3} + 4)^2 + {16x^2 \over 9} +
        {16z^2 \over 9})^4}\right)^ {- {1\over 4}} - 1
\end{dmath*}
\caption{Bloomenthal Algebraic Jack}
\label{eq:BloomenthalJack}
\end{eqn}
Let's talk about Equation~\ref{eq:BloomenthalJack}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that the OP is using a two-column IEEE format...

Comment: @Werner that's a good point. I wasn't able to successfully install the `IEEEtran` class when I went to answer this question; if you can use it, do you know if this solution still works?